# How to remove custom element while avoiding detached DOM trees?

Tags: dom, polymer, web-component

I'm using Polymer to create custom elements (web components) and have run into a problem when removing them from the DOM. Say I have an element like this:

```
<link rel="import" href="../polymer/polymer.html">

<polymer-element name="demo-element">
    <template>
        <h1 on-tap="{{ titleTap }}">A custom demo element</h1>
    </template>
    <script>
        Polymer('demo-element', {
            titleTap: function() { // do something }
        });
    </script>
</polymer-element>
```

Then when removing the `<demo-element></demo-element>` from the DOM I will end up with a detached DOM tree with a reference to the H1 element (according to Chrome Devtools). It seems to me that it's the `polymerWrapper` that references it.

According to the documentation in [Polymer API reference](http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/polymer.html#bindings) the framework should automatically handle the unbind. Is this not working or am I misunderstanding it?

Is this something that in the future will be handled by the browsers or will we need to depend on frameworks like Polymer to do keep our memory clean? (So what I'm asking is if there are any proposals or standards relating to this)

Comment: Those docs refer to listeners and `{{}}` bindings being removed over time. I'm not super familiar with looking at detached nodes in the DevTools profiler...but I don't see an `HTMLHeadingElement` anywhere in detached nodes. I only see remnants of the template's document-fragment? http://jsbin.com/zaxivezo/1/edit

Comment: Thanks for reply Eric. I find this hard to debug this with JSBin but I do get "A custom demo element" text node as still being referenced after being removed. I think a strategy for this should be part of the web components work as using custom elements dynamically will of course be a common use case. For example, is JS scoped to the component like CSS is? If it is, then it should hopefully be straight-forward to clean it on "detached". If it isn't, shouldn't it be?

Comment: Found this article by Steve Souders that discuss JavaScript scope in web components: [HTML Imports: scope, security, and suggestions](http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2013/12/02/html-imports-scope-security-and-suggestions/) and from that I understand that the JS in a web component run in the global scope. I agree with Steve, it should be scoped to the component, especially since CSS is. I'll continue to look into what a solution would require and if it belongs to web components or the module tag.

Comment: Your <polymer-element> definition continues to exist after all instances are gone, and there is a text node inside the template that continues to exist. Because it's in a template, it's not in the main document, and may be listed as 'detached'. Are you sure this is not what you seeing?